# rails create form-tags default values from a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

iam trying to save the current state of a form in the sessionhash (with ajax) and redisplay it after a pagerefresh oder reopened browserwindow:

```
def save
  session[:last_order] = params.dup
end
def new
  @last_state = session[:last_order] || {}
  ...
end
```

that was the easy part.

the problem is, when iam showing the form on the `new` action, the `@last_state` could be an empty hash, so how can i handle the form-tags without checking the existance of the key on every form-tag creation?

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'product_id', product.id, @last_state.has_key? 'product_id' && @last_state['product_id'] == product.id %>
```

i just want to write a simple line like this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'product_id', product.id, @last_state['product_id'] == product.id %>
```

or even better:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'product_id', product.id, @last_state.product_id == product.id %>
```

secondary question: i heard of a rails-way to treat hashes like objects but i forgot that. can anyone show me the direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about setting up a default state for @last_state

```
def new
  @last_state = session[:last_order] || {product_id: 0}
  ...
end
```